# C2DM - HttpsURLConnection is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Tags: google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I'm trying to send c2dm from cloud to device. But I'm getting some errors stating that 
**HttpsURLConnection is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment**

Please let me know how to fix this error. Thanks so much in advance.

Following is my code:

```
package test3;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import com.sun.net.ssl.*;

public class C2DMTest 
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception 
    {
        String auth = authorize();
        System.out.println("C2DM Authorizaton Key for the cloud:"+auth);
        if (auth == null) 
        {
            System.out.println("No authorization returned");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        sendMessage(auth);
    }

    /**
     * Perform an authorization request to access Google's C2DM
     * API.
     *
     * @return The retrieved authorization request.
     */
    private static String authorize() throws Exception 
    {
        String accountType = "GOOGLE";
        String service = "ac2dm";

        String email = "emial@gmail.com";
        String passwd = "emial";


        StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
        params.append("accountType=").append(accountType)
                .append("&Email=").append(URLEncoder.encode(email, UTF8))
                .append("&Passwd=").append(URLEncoder.encode(passwd, UTF8))
                .append("&service=").append(service)
                .append("&source=").append(source);
        byte[] postData = params.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));

        //------------------
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        //--------------------------
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int sw = conn.getResponseCode();
        //System.out.println(sw);

        switch (sw) 
        {
            case 503:
                System.out.println("Service unavailable");
                break;
            case 401:
                System.out.println(" Invalid authentication token");
                break;
            default:
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
                int len = -1;
                while ((len = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(bytes, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                String input = baos.toString();
                Map<String, String> res = parseResponse(input);
                return res.get("Auth");
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Parses a response string into a usable data map.
     *
     * @param response The response from Google
     * @return A Map representation.
     */
    private static Map<String, String> parseResponse(String response) 
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (response != null) 
        {
            String[] lines = response.split("\n");
            for (String line : lines) 
            {
                String[] parts = line.split("=");
                if (parts.length == 2) 
                {
                    map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    private static String UTF8 = "UTF-8";


    /**
     * Send message to mobile device.
     *
     * @param cl Google API auth code.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void sendMessage(String cl) throws IOException {
        String key = "invalid";

        StringBuilder postDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        postDataBuilder.append("registration_id").append("=").append(key);
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("collapse_key").append("=").append("0");
        postDataBuilder.append("&").append("data.payload").append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode("test-content", UTF8));
        byte[] postData = postDataBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8);

        URL url = new URL("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");

        HostnameVerifier hVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession
                    session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(hVerifier);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="+cl);

        //------------------
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        //--------------------------
        out.write(postData);
        out.close();

        int sw = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("" + sw);
        switch (sw) {
            case 200:
                System.out.println("Success, but check for errors in the body");
                break;
            case 503:
                System.out.println("Service unavailable");
                break;
            case 401:
                System.out.println(" Invalid authentication token");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HttpsURLConnection class isn't the problem. I had an issue with the Google Client Auth returning a 401 error to my application server but it was solved on another SO thread describing that something could be going wrong with the account you registerd with on C2DM. The solution was to simply re-register and things started working immediately for me with google responding with a 200 response code. See the solved post here: [Android C2DM getting (401) Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748663/android-c2dm-getting-401-unauthorized)